# Can a WCF operation contract return a boolean value?

Tags: wcf

Is the following signature correct (in VB)?

```
<OperationContract()>
Function Validate(Byval Param As Integer) As Boolean
```

I heard that "Operation contracts" cannot return boolean values.  Is it true or it is a blunder?  Of course, I did not test it yet.

Comment: Where did you hear that?? Reference?? Link?? This is utter b***s*** Anything that can be expressed and represented in XSD (XML Schema) can be used in WCF services - string, int, date, bool and a lot more

Comment: Excuse the zombie thread revival, but I feel like naming and shaming - I just came across this as the "correct" answer in a uCertify practice exam for Microsoft's WCF examination. The quality of their material is generally in the same realm across the syllabus. If you're ever sitting the examination, I'd recommend looking elsewhere for information and practice tests...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can return a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

According to this document and the example provided:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx

if you are using a MessageContract parameter, then you CAN NOT return boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Operation Contracts can return almost all types, including boolean, void.